# Can Octomap use multiple point clouds as sources?

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a laser producing a point cloud on topic `/laser/points2` and a stereo camera pair producing a point cloud on topic `/stereo/points2`. The subscribed topics of [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server#Subscribed_Topics) shows that it listens for the topic `cloud_in`. Currently, I am remapping with

```
<remap from="cloud_in" to="laser/points2"/>
```

If I then add

```
<remap from="cloud_in" to="stereo/points2"/>
```

then `octomap_server` only subscribes to `/stereo/points2`. Is there a way to configure `octomap_server` to subscribe to multiple point clouds? I realize it will be up to me to make sure that the points in the different point clouds are aligned properly through calibration, `/tf`, and timing offsets. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44055/can-octomap-use-multiple-point-clouds-as-sources?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would do the remapping the other way around. Make both point clouds publish to the same topic by adding remappings to the sensor nodes.

Alternatively, you can set up a relay using the [topic_tools relay](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/relay). Just relay both point clouds to the same topic and remap octomap's cloud_in topic to it.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-09-19**:
This worked, thanks. For some reason I can't accept it as an answer by clicking on the check icon, but I would if I could.